# MVC 4 Custom HTML Helper Vs Custom Display Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, display-templates

So, I've an obj structure something like below.

**ComparedObject:**

```
public List<string> Objs { get; set; }
public string PropName { get; set; }
```

**ModelObj:**

```
public List<ComparedObject> CObjs { get; set; }
```

I've a scenario in which I would need to loop through "CObjs" and render Comparison table of `List<string>` object whose lengh would be 3 records (in a row).

I've achieved this using a Custom HTML Helper to make it generic enough to be used in other screens. But, I was told that Custom *Display Template* would be faster and better at performance in this scenario.

Please explain what is the best option and why.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you have written your html helper correctly there is not reason why it would be any different from the `DisplayTempate` In order to display the template you need to use the `DisplayFor()` method which is a html helper  extension method as well

Comment: I agree to that but I'm hearing from my Architect that Display Templates would be better at performance when compare to HTML Helper. So, I'm totally confused and composed this question. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Why do you think it would be faster? In order to render a `DisplayTemplate` you need to use `@Html.DisplayFor()` which **is a** html helper. `DisplayFor()` in turn calls the `TemplateHelper` method to get the `ViewEngine` and find the template and eventually render it based on all the html helper methods in the template. Its all so fast I have not bothered to run performance tests but using `DisplayFor()` would almost certainly be slower than using your own helper - but of course that depend on the code in your helper.

Comment: My only comment would be that with HTML Helper you are rendering HTML in code, where as Display Templates are files, and as such might be easier for Front-End people to modify, attach classes, etc. As for performance, I am with Stephen.